# Determine $q$ so the matrix has equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $A_2$ and vector $b_2$ is given as:

$A_2$=$\begin{bmatrix}
2     & 2 & q      \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1      & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
                       \text{And  $b_2$}    =\begin{bmatrix}
1      \\
2 \\ 
4
\end{bmatrix}$

> Determine $q$ so the matrix equation $A_2x=b_2$ has a unique solution.

Should I start to swap $R_2$ with $R_1$, and then swap $R_3$ with $R_2$ and then row reduce the matrix?

Comment: This will lead in a $3\times3 $ system of equations with one parameter-$q$. What will be the condition for it to have a unique solution? Show us what have you tried so far..

Comment: @AdiT: Yes, you can use RREF for the augmented system. Another approach (assuming the system is consistent and has a solution), is to find the det of $A_2$.

Comment: @Moo Is it correct starting to swap as I describe above, and the rref?

Comment: Typically, you would do a swap (and the first one you chose is correct), do some reduction and then possibly swap more rows (and in this case, yes the second swap is also valid, but do a reduction first as you typically don't know to swap unless you reduce).

Comment: @Moo, the determinant approach is probably easier, but the OP may not have covered the concept of the determinant (yet).

Comment: @pyrazolam: Agree, and that is why it says another approach - assuming he the reduction first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system of equations represented by a coefficient matrix $A$ has a unique solution if its determinant is $\text{NOT EQUAL to 0: iff det(A)≠0}$

$\implies A_2 \neq0$

$\implies \begin{bmatrix}
2     & 2 & q      \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1      & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$

$\implies2(3-1)-2(3+1)+q(1+1)\neq0$

$\implies2\times2-2\times 4+q\times 2\neq0$

$\implies2\times(2- 4+q)\neq0$

$\implies2\times(q-2)\neq0$

$\implies(q-2)\neq0$

$\implies q\neq2$

Therefore, value of $q$ can be any real number except $2$

Note:  Rank of matrix $A$ should not be less than number of variables for unique solution of given system.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a single value of $q$ for which the matrix is degenerate and thus the equation does not have a unique solution. Note that the first row is a multiple of the second row for $q=2$, so this is the only value that you can't choose.